# When and why did Apple make "On My iPhone" the default account for Contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I've been using Exchange with Google Contacts to manage my iPhone contacts. Recently, I noticed my Google Contacts wouldn't sync when I added a new contact to my phone. Today I found a setting under Contacts for "Default Account: Exchange or On My iPhone," and the second one is chosen by default.

[image]

When did they make this change? Why did they make this change? And is there any way to merge the two contact groups now that I've added a number of contacts to my phone?

Answer (score 3):

Contacts are added to your native iOS Address Book (called "Contacts" and located on your home screen) by default. This ensures contacts are added locally and synced properly (through iTunes)

The addition of an outside contacts manager (as seen by using Gmail) is an added feature and brought along with Gmail. However, some may simply just want to use Google's email services without storing their contacts. Keeping contacts stored locally on the device is always more beneficial because it has less chance to cause commotion or confusion. Tech savvy people can always change this behaviour, but by default, it is not the optimal choice.

So it's not a change they made, but rather the default setting that simply takes precedent. I'm not sure what version that setting snuck it's way into iOS, I'm sorry.

If you'd like to transfer your contacts from your iPhone to Gmail, you can do the following:

**In Windows 7**

1. In iTunes, make sure you select syncing of your contacts with
   *Windows Contacts* under the Contacts section.
2. Once they are present in Windows Contacts, export them to CSV.
3. Then head over to Gmail, log in, pull up the Contacts page, and
   select "Import" from the "More" drop-down menu.

*Note: An easy to follow tutorial can also be found [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/import-iphone-contacts-to-gmail-via-windows-7/).*

**In Mac OS X**

1. Open Address Book after you've synced your iPhone with iTunes.
2. Click on an entry and hit CMD+A (this will select all the
   entries).
3. Then go to File > Export vCard...
4. Then head over to Gmail, log in, and follow the same "Import"
   procedure above.

*Note: Additionally, Gmail supports syncing your contacts with your Mac using their [Contact Sync](http://www.google.com/support/contactsync/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92997&rd=1) service.*